# timeout ConnectionError error while downloading package from s3 bucket on ec2: aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a test EC2 instance and download an initial package from S3 Bucket via Cloud formation Script but I am getting below error while using.

```
cfn-init
```

Does my instance need internet connection to execute cfn-init?

"2018-04-03 01:23:29,660 [ERROR] ConnectionError
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 162, in _retry
  File "cfnbootstrap\util.pyc", line 234, in _timeout
ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))"

Below is the template i am using to create the instance and download the package. Instance creation is successful and I am able to RDP the instance but no luck with package download.

```
{
"AWSTemplateFormatVersion" : "2010-09-09",

"Description" : "Test Stack",

    "Parameters" : {
      "SubnetId" : {
          "Description" : "Subnets Id for EC2 instances.",
          "Type" : "String",
          "AllowedValues" : [ "xxxxxx"]
      },
      "KeyName" : {
          "Description" : "The EC2 Key Pair to create Windows instance",
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::KeyPair::KeyName",
          "ConstraintDescription" : "must be the name of an existing EC2 KeyPair."
      },
      "WebInstanceType" : {
          "Description" : "WebServer EC2 instance type",
          "Type" : "String",
          "Default" : "t2.micro",
          "AllowedValues" : [ "t1.micro", "t2.micro", "t2.small", "t2.medium", "m1.small", "m1.medium", "m1.large", "m1.xlarge", "m2.xlarge", "m2.2xlarge", "m2.4xlarge", "m3.medium", "m3.large", "m3.xlarge", "m3.2xlarge", "c1.medium", "c1.xlarge", "c3.large", "c3.xlarge", "c3.2xlarge", "c3.4xlarge", "c3.8xlarge", "c4.large", "c4.xlarge", "c4.2xlarge", "c4.4xlarge", "c4.8xlarge", "g2.2xlarge", "r3.large", "r3.xlarge", "r3.2xlarge", "r3.4xlarge", "r3.8xlarge", "i2.xlarge", "i2.2xlarge", "i2.4xlarge", "i2.8xlarge", "hi1.4xlarge", "hs1.8xlarge", "cr1.8xlarge", "cc2.8xlarge", "cg1.4xlarge"],
          "ConstraintDescription" : "must be a valid EC2 instance type."
      },
      "WebImageId" : {
          "Description" : "Id of the AMI to be loaded on the EC2 instance for webserver",
          "Type" : "String"
      }
  },

  "Resources": {
      "WebServer": {
          "Type" : "AWS::EC2::Instance",
          "Metadata": {
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication": {
                  "S3AccessCreds": {
                      "type": "S3",
                      "roleName": "InstanceRole",
                      "buckets" : ["test-bucket"]
                  }
              },
              "AWS::CloudFormation::Init": {
                  "config": {
                      "sources": {
                          "c:\\S3\\SSMS": "https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/test-bucket/test.zip"
                      }
                  }
              }
          },

          "Properties" : {
              "IamInstanceProfile" : "xxxxxxx",
              "InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior" : "stop",
              "KeyName" : { "Ref" : "KeyName" },
              "InstanceType" : { "Ref" : "WebInstanceType" },
              "ImageId" : { "Ref" : "WebImageId" },
              "Tags" : [
              {  "Key" : "Name", "Value" : "test1"}
              ],
              "NetworkInterfaces" : [
              {
                  "DeviceIndex"         : "0",
                  "DeleteOnTermination" : "true",
                  "SubnetId"                : { "Ref" : "SubnetId" },
                  "GroupSet"                : [ "xxxxxxx, xxxxxxx" ]
              }],
              "UserData" : {
                  "Fn::Base64" : { 
                      "Fn::Join" : ["", [
                      "<script>\n",
                        "cfn-init.exe -s ", 
                        {"Ref" : "AWS::StackId"}, 
                        " -r RetailWebServer --region ", 
                        {"Ref" : "AWS::Region"},
                        " --http-proxy http://proxy.aws.xxxxxx.local:8080 \n",
                    "</script>\n"
                    ]]
                }
            }
        }

    }   
}
```

}

Comment: You ask if you need an Internet connect (inferring that you don't) but then you state that you can RDP to the instance (inferring that you do). Please provide more details about your configuration.

Comment: If your instance is located in a private subnet, you can access S3 in the same region using a VPC endpoint.

Comment: @John Hanley: Does the newly created instance need an internet connection to access S3  as it is in private subnet? please can you specify what other configuration you are looking for.

Comment: An Internet connection (e.g. access to the public Internet) is not required to access S3 in the same region via an S3 endpoint.

Comment: @JohnHanley still not able to access the bucket and getting the same error, tried using --https-proxy too. I can access the s3 bucket if i rdp the instance and change proxy settings in browser.

Comment: edited the code to include --http-proxy